# Yii Security Risk : How to set to null email and password on form

Tags: yii

I have a form and I use `$model->unsetAttributes(array('email', 'password'));` to set the `email` and `password` properties to `null`.

This should work, but it does not.

I need to set them to `null` if the `email` or `password` that the user gaved were not correct.

On the form, the old values are still there.

Comment: problem soved ... it was the browser cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to empty your browser cache memory . 
Also try with other browsers .